# How to use bluetooth in android and send data to other device

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, file-sharing

I am developing an android application which will send the files to the mobile devices via bluetooth
please anyone can help me out about how to use the bluetooth on emulator for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that the standard SDK emulator does not support bluetooth.  I ended up buying a used tablet for my bluetooth development.

Comment: Ok thanks digitalhack so i will also have to go out for buying a new device.